# Convert date format from dd-mm-yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: r, date-format

I would like convert my date format from dd-mm-yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy

Data:

```
         date
1 22-Jul-2020
```

Current code:

```
format(as.Date(df$date, '%d:%m:%Y'), '%d/%m/%Y' )
[1] NA NA
```

Desired Output:

```
         date
1 22/07/2020
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `format` in `as.Date` should match the input format.  It is `%d` followed by `-`, then abbrevation for month (`%b`) followed by `-` and 4 digit year (`%Y`)

```
df$date <- format(as.Date(df$date, '%d-%b-%Y'), '%d/%m/%Y' )
df$date
#[1] "22/07/2020"
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(date = "22-Jul-2020"), class = "data.frame", row.names = "1")
```

Comment: beat me to it (although I also wanted to ask OP to show us `dput(df)` in case there was anything weird hiding in there)

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
library(lubridate)
df <- data.frame(date = c("22-Jul-2020"))

df$date <- dmy(df$date)
df$date <- format(df$date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
#       date
#1 22/07/2020
```